# Ubuntu 20.04 No WIFI

Tags: wireless

A few days ago my ubuntu worked well, but today I can not find wifi in settings.

CHIPSET： ASUS X570
NETWORK CONTROLLER: INTEL AX200

By typing in `lspci -v` in the command line, I can see the network controller information in return.

I have installed the package backport-iwlwifi-dkms.

Reboot has been tried for several times.

The returns of `lshw -C network` are

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc700000-fc703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 03
       serial: a8:5e:45:50:a6:4b
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 ip=10.0.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:37 memory:fc600000-fc61ffff ioport:f000(size=32) memory:fc620000-fc623fff
```

Fast boot has been disabled.

The returns of  `dmesg | grep iwl` are

```
[    2.713364] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.746565] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:05:00.0 failed with error -110
[ 1422.203907] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:05:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Hope you guys could help me solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Will you add output of `rfkill list` and `nmcli radio wifi`?

Comment: Disable Windows Fast Boot feature if it is a dual boot.

Comment: I've been having the same problem without dual boot. Any luck so far? @HM47